# Haskell: return a list of all substrees in Binary Tree. Is my code correct?

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, subtree

So I am trying to implement a functoin in Haskell that accepts a Binary Tree and returns a list of all subtrees where order and repetition does not matter but all substrees must be present at least once. Here is my code:

```
data BinTree a = Empty | Node (BinTree a) a (BinTree a) deriving (Eq,Show)

subtrees :: BinTree a -> [BinTree a]
subtrees Empty = [Empty]
subtrees (Node tL x tR) = [Node tL x tR] ++ subtrees tL ++ subtrees tR
```

**Here is my data set**

```
(Node (Node (Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 1 Empty) 3 Empty) 4 (Node Empty 2 Empty))
```

**Here is my result**

```
[Node (Node (Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 1 Empty) 3 Empty) 4 (Node Empty 2 Empty),
Node (Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 1 Empty) 3 Empty,Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 1 Emp
ty,Node Empty 1 Empty,Node Empty 2 Empty]
```

For some reason I am somewhat doubtful of this implementation and I would appreciate any feedback! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks ok. Only answer the question: what is a list of all subtrees of a Empty tree?

Comment: So I suppose actualy [Empty] insead of just [] . Correct?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test something like this, in my opinion, is to think of *properties* that you expect your function to satisfy, and then write some QuickCheck tests to try them out. The best thing about QuickCheck is that if it finds a problem, it will try to tell you the *simplest possible case that fails*! So let's begin...

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Test.QuickCheck
import Control.Applicative
```

What's a good property to test? Well, if we have two trees, t1 and t2, and combine them with a new node, then calling `subtree` on the combined tree should give us a list that includes `subtree t1`, `subtree t2`, plus the entire tree. The node type doesn't affect the logic, so I chose Char. You can probably think of a better name for this property.

```
prop_combining_works :: BinTree Char -> Char -> BinTree Char -> Property
prop_combining_works t1 x t2 =
  property $ subtrees t == t : subtrees t1 ++ subtrees t2
  where t = Node t1 x t2
```

NOTE: I didn't expect this to work without sorting the results of `subtree` in some way, but by happy accident, it does. But that may change, depending on how you decide to return for `subtree Empty`! Also, you may need to eliminate duplicates in expression to the right of `==`.

Next, we need a way to generate random trees to test with. The code below may look complicated, but what it's saying is that test data for the `BinTree` type can be either `Empty`, or a `Node` build up with two arbitrarily chosen subtrees and an arbitrarily chosen `Char`.

```
instance Arbitrary (BinTree Char) where
  arbitrary = do
    oneof [return Empty, Node <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary <*> arbitrary]
```

Add this to your code, and run QuickCheck:

```
λ> quickCheck prop_combining_works
Loading package QuickCheck-2.6 ... linking ... done.
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Now you can think of other properties to test.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! Unfortunately I am very new to Haskell and all of these are definitely beyond the scope of knowledge at the moment.

Comment: Fair enough. But you might want to keep this answer handy, and come back to it when you've learned a little more. Don't put it off too long, though. QuickCheck saves you loads of time, and can help you produce bullet-proof code. And you don't really need to understand that `Arbitrary` stuff to begin using it -- I certainly didn't understand that part when I started. At first, I just looked at examples that other people had done, and tweaked them to meet my needs.